# Posting multiples dynamically created inputs and inserting them into a MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a table that was dynamically created using jquery. Now I am sending the inputs, that are array, of course, to a database. The fields are `customCLASSE[]`, `customQTY[]`, `customPRICE[]`... and this is my script that inserts the data within MySQL:

```
    if ($_POST['customCLASSE']) {
        foreach ( $_POST['customCLASSE'] as $key=>$value  ) {
           $query  = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO booking_multiday_detail (classe) VALUES ('$value')");
        }
    }
```

It is working very good but my question is: How do I insert the other inputs (`customQTY[]`, `customPRICE[]`...) within the same foreach in the same time that customCLASSE is being inserted?

Comment: you can't use one foreach for multiple arrays .. try doing the 'for' way then (setting a iterator variable and iterating through it) .. also use sql multi insert (insert multiple rows in single query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$key` is the index of array on looping cycle.

So if your other arrays sorted as well as customCLASSE you can access other arrays' value by $key like this,

```
if ($_POST['customCLASSE']) {
        foreach ( $_POST['customCLASSE'] as $key=>$value  ) {
           $customQty = $_POST['customQTY'][$key];
           $customPRICE= $_POST['customQTY'][$key];
           //change the query
           //....
           $query  = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO booking_multiday_detail (classe) VALUES ('$value')");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice @ocanal! Thank you! I was trying something very similar and it works as yours as well. Instead of using the $key, I have created a variable called counter that increases by one within the loop indicating the exact number of the array item that I want to be added within the database table. Thanks!